# Printing the output from a loop under two different titles

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, format, grouping

I want to try format an output to be listed under a title.

I made a python (v3.6) script, which checks urls (contained in a textile) and output's whether it's safe or malicious.

Loop statement:

```
"""
This iterates through each url in the textfile and checks it against google's database.
"""

f = open("file.txt", "r")

for weburl in f:

    sb = threat_matches_find(weburl) # Google API module

    if url_checker == {}:  # the '{}' represent = Safe URL
        print ("Safe :", url)

    else:
        print ("Malicious :", url)
```

The result out put from this is:

```
>>>python url_checker.py 
Safe : url1.com
Malicious : url2.com
Safe : url3.com
Malicious: url4.com
Safe : url5.com
```

The objective is to get the url to be listed/sorted under a Title (group), as follows:

If the url is safe, print the url under 'Safe URL', else 'Malicious'.

```
>>> python url_checker.py
Safe URLs:
url1.com
url3.com
url5.com

Malicious URLs:
url2.com
url4.com
```

I was unsuccessful in finding other post related to my problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what's `url_checker`? How does that relate to `sb`?

Answer (score 2):

You could append to lists as you loop and then print when both lists are populated:

```
safe = []
malicious = []
for weburl in f:
    sb = threat_matches_find(weburl) # Google API module
    if url_checker == {}:  # the '{}' represent = Safe URL
        safe.append(url)
    else:
        malicious.append(url)

print('Safe URLs', *safe, '', sep='\n')
print('Malicious URLs', *malicious, '', sep='\n')
```

Sample Output:

```
safe = ['url1.com','url3.com','url5.com']
malicious = ['url2.com','url4.com']

Safe URLs
url1.com
url3.com
url5.com

Malicious URLs
url2.com
url4.com
```

Comment: `print('Safe URLs', *safe, sep='\n')` would be cleaner. You can then add extra an extra newline at the end with `print('Safe URLs', *safe, '', sep='\n')`